# Import ES6: Giving an Alias Name to the Package

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

Please take a look at the following import statement:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
```

Is it possible to give an alias to the name of the **package** that is being imported -- i.e., in this case to `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome`. 
 That way I wouldn't have to write out the entire project name each time.

For clarity sake, I'm looking for a final result where I could do something like this:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from 'fa'
```

or this

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@custom/fa'
```

With `fa` (or `@custom/fa`) is a name that I created that references the actual `@fortawesome/react-fontawesome` library.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: AFAIK you can't but you can create a file containing `export * from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'` and then you import this file which has your own custom name

Comment: You probably need to look at your bundler, you can do it with bundler, something like this [`webpack.resolve`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#resolving-rules-in-webpack)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im assuming you're using webpack. If so you can use the [Webpack.resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) functionality. You just need to edit your `webpack.config.js` and setup like the following:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    //...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            fa: path.resolve(__dirname, '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome')
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Your import would become

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from 'fa'
```

Comment: Nice and clean.

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a file that stores your dependencies in an object. I will call this file dependencies.js.

```
export default const dependencies = {
  FA: '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome',
  ...
  ...
}
```

Then you can import these at the very top of each of your javascript files and use it to import further dependencies.

```
import dependencies from './dependencies';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from dependencies.FA
```

Comment: This is clever.  The only downside is that I now have two imports instead of one.  What I would like is one import -- with a shorten syntax.

Comment: Very understandable. If you in fact are using webpack the solution from Riddell is probably cleaner. I just wanted to give a suggestion that can be applied in all use cases.